# What's the meaning of the phrase "may be bound for reference"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[image]

I don't understand the meaning of the phrase "...and may be bound for reference"? Could you please rephrase the second part of this sentence?

Answer (score 3):

I take it to mean "may be collected in bound volumes (i.e. books with hard covers) so that people can find them in a library". It's not very clear, though.

Comment: Yes, documents can be bound. From the verb bind. It cannot be anything else here. Law and medical articles are frequently collected and bound in hard-cover books.